# Connection Timing out while install p4python using pip

Tags: python, pip, perforce, ubuntu-15.04, p4python

There seems to be a connection time out when trying to install p4python on a ubuntu system. I am trying install this using pip on an ubuntu install on a vm.

Here is the stack trace:

```
~$ pip install p4python
Downloading/unpacking p4python
Downloading p4python-2016.1.1415051.tar.gz (83kB): 83kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py) egg_info for package p4python
Attempting to load API from ftp.perforce.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py", line 611, in <module>
    p4_api_dir = get_api_dir()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py", line 532, in get_api_dir
    p4ftp = P4APIFtp()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.ftp = FTP(PERFORCE_FTP)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Attempting to load API from ftp.perforce.com

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py", line 611, in <module>

p4_api_dir = get_api_dir()

File "/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py", line 532, in get_api_dir

p4ftp = P4APIFtp()

File "/tmp/pip-build-rsprca/p4python/setup.py", line 60, in __init__

self.ftp = FTP(PERFORCE_FTP)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__

self.connect(host)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 135, in connect

self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection

raise err

socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-           rsprca/p4python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/cicd/.pip/pip.log
```

Help with debugging this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Can you `ftp ftp.perforce.com` or `curl ftp.perforce.com` from your system? That is, is that address reachable for you? Perhaps Perforce were doing some maintenance on that system at the moment that you attempted your install?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some firewall limitations (or using proxy).
Please use following command instead:

```
pip install p4python config --global http.sslVerify false --trusted-host pypi.org
```